# Angular : Adding Attribute directive on Element Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For my project, i'm currently developping custom form / inputs directive.

For example, I have the following directive :

```
angular.module('myApp').directive("textField", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl : "/common/tpl/form/text-field.html",
        scope : {
            label   : "@",
            model   : "="
        }
    };
});
```

with the associated template :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{fieldId}}" class="col-lg-2 control-label">{{label |translate}}</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{fieldId}}" ng-model="model" placeholder="{{label|translate}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

I have many more custom fields ( date, select, double select, and so on... )

The usage is simple :

```
<text-field label="app.myLabel" model="myObj.myAttribute"></text-field>
```

The idea is to cleanup the main template by avoiding to verbosely add labels on every fields. Very common need i believe.

**Now the problem :**

Now I need to add custom validation to my input models.

I did a naive approach which was to create a validation directive :

```
directive('myValidation', function (){
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
                // do some validation
                return value;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and then to use it like this :

```
<text-field label="app.myLabel" model="myObj.myAttribute" myValidation="validationOptions"></text-field>
```

But of course this doesnt work, simple because the text-field directive which is replace=true "erases" the validation directive on it's element.

Can someone tell one what is the correct approach to do "custom input with presentation" directive, while allowing the validation part to be declared on the directive ( here text-field ) and used on the directive's input ?

Per example, is there a way to say "attributes on my element directive will be 'copied' to inside my directive ?"

aka :

```
<text-field label="app.myLabel" model="myObj.myAttribute" **myValidation="validationOptions"**></text-field>
```

would result in :

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{fieldId}}" class="col-lg-2 control-label">{{label |translate}}</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{fieldId}}" ng-model="model" **myValidation="validationOptions"** placeholder="{{label|translate}}">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Or am I simply missing something ?

I would like to avoid using transclusion to resolve this issue, because this would oblige the form template to look like this :

```
<field label="myLabel">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{fieldId}}" ng-model="model" placeholder= {{label|translate}}">    
</field>
```

which is just uselessly verbose in my opinion. But i'm starting to ask myself if there really is another option ?

Maybe the trick can be done in the pre (or post ?) directve link function, where I would copy attributes/ directive from the text-field tag to it's child (input) tag ?

Could someone just light the way for me there ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try this:

- Write a `validate` directive. This will have a controller that exposes an `addValidationFunction(fn)` and a `getValidationFunction()` methods.
- Have the `myValidation` directive require the `validate` controller and call `ctrl.addValidationFunction(myValidationImplementation)` where `myValidationImplementation` is a function implementing the validation logic for this specific directive.
- Write another directive, `validateInner`. This will require optionally the `validate` controller from its parent. This directive will also require the `ngModel` controller. If it finds the `validate` controller, it calls `ctrl.getValidationFunction()` and registers the function with the `ngModel` i.e.:

  ```
  require: ["^?validate", "ngModel"],
  link: function(scope,el,attrs,ctrls) {
      if( ctrls[0] != null ) {
          var validationFn = ctrls[0].getValidationFunction();
          // register validationFn with ngModel = ctrls[1]
      }
      ...
  }
  ```
- In the template of your `textField`:

  ```
  <input validate-inner type="text" class="form-control" id="{{fieldId}}" ng-model="model" placeholder="{{label|translate}}">
  ```

Usage:

```
<text-field label="app.myLabel" model="myObj.myAttribute"
    validate my-validation="validationOptions"></text-field>
```

**NOTE 1**: I am not sure if a `replace:true` directive wipes the other directives. If so, it is not consistent behaviour.

**NOTE 2**: The `myValidation` directive gets called as `<xxx my-validation>` (note camelCase → dash-case). If your code above is not a typo, then this is why `<text-field`> seems to wipe `myValidation`.

Comment: I was hallucinating, a replace: true does not wipes the others directives, camelCase issue was all it was. But you are right, this is the approach I finally had to do, thanks